# Using count_if() to find the same string value

Tags: c++, algorithm, lambda

I tried using a lambda expression and `count_if()` to find the same string value in a `vector`, but it didn't work. The error message is:

> variable 'str' cannot be implicitly captured in a lambda with no capture-default specified

```cpp
std::vector<std::string> hello{"Mon","Tue", "Wes", "perfect","Sun"};

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < hello.size(); i++)
{
    int n=0;
    std::string str=hello[i];
    n=std::count_if(hello.begin(),hello.end(),[](std::string s){return s==str;});
    std::cout<<n;
}
```

Comment: Use lambda captures list to capture `str`, like this: `[&str](std::string s){return s==str;}`

Comment: Thank you so much, sir, I was wondering what is that [] for. when I use count_if and lambda expression to find the same value of int,I can leave that [] empty. what's the difference here?

Comment: @康桓瑋 `[&]` would be even simpler.

Comment: @Steven please show an example. You can't capture variables in a lambda without telling it what to capture, so if it worked without capturing then your use-case must have been different.

Comment: Just change `[](std::string s){` to `[&](std::string s){` and your code will work!

Comment: `std::count(hello.begin(), hello.end(), str);` should work just fine. There's no need for the added complexity of `count_if` and a lambda here.

Comment: @RemyLebeau  After I read the post, I understand that I have a misunderstanding of Lambda expression. I didn't capture anything here, I just compare it with a number like 0 that doesn't need to be captured by the lambda expression.

Comment: @Steven exactly, that example is not capturing anything, it is simply acting on the input parameter of the lambda, which will receive each element of the `vector`. That is not the case with the code in your question, which is trying to compare `vector` elements to an outside value, so the lambda needs to capture that value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@Steven
The brackets `[]` of lambda functions, are called a *capture list*. They define the scope of variables that the lambda function uses. See [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda).

When you use this formatting `[&]`, it means you can see all the variables (by reference) of the current scope in your lambda function. So the type of variables doesn't matter.

For your example, when you write:

```
s == str
```

The lambda function only knows about the variable `s`, which is passed as an argument. To see the `str`, you can use either of these:

1. `[&]`, pass everything by reference
2. `[&str]`, pass only the variable `str` as reference

Note, there are also ways to pass by value.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation. Now I understand how the lambda expression works.

Answer (score 1):

This function has the same mechanism, only it uses `<hash>` and `<unordered_map>` to store the values and the number of times each is repeated (if it is greater than `1` *occurrence*).

```
template <typename T>
void elements(vector<T>& e) 
{
    auto h = [](const T* v) { return std::hash<T>()(*v); };
    auto eq = [](const T* v1, const T* v2) { return v1->compare(*v2) == 0; };
    std::unordered_map<const T*, size_t, decltype(h), decltype(eq)> m(e.size(), h, eq);

    // Count occurances.
    for (auto v_i = e.cbegin(); v_i != e.cend(); ++v_i)
        ++m[&(*v_i)];

    // Print value that occur more than once:
    for (auto m_i = m.begin(); m_i != m.end(); ++m_i)
        if (m_i->second > 1)
            std::cout << *m_i->first << ": " << m_i->second << std::endl;
}
```

[Example](https://godbolt.org/z/334bexK8s)